# Can I programatically check if antivirus settings are "managed by an administrator"?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

We are doing a company wide audit, and need to prove that each machine's Windows Defender settings displays "Some settings are managed by an administrator" and does not allow any changes by an end user.

I'm not sure of any powershell or C# command that can check this.  Being domain joined is not enough evidence, and they need a specific example of end users not being able to change their settings.  Rather than take screenshots of every single machine, is there another way to do this with a command that shows users are unable to change settings?

Either Powershell or C# if possible. Thanks in advance to anyone that can figure this out! I've included an image above of the page I'd like to confirm is set to be managed by an admin.

Here's an image of what I want to search for:

[image: Virus and thread protection settings screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps you can query the local computer policies and show that the policy that enforces these settings is enabled? `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\real-time protection`

Comment: You should be setting that with a  domain-level group policy, and then there's no need to audit it, because the GP won't allow it to be changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a PCI auditor and just "having" policies in place isn't enough. We need a way to audit that they are in fact "working" without only seeing that GP is turned on. Trust me, we think its just as ridiculous.